# why do we use recursive type to implement stack instead of list?

Tags: f#, stack

I thought `list` is exactly the implementation of a persistent `stack`. However, when I came across articles about the actual functional implementation, they always use recursive type / discriminated unions. Why don't they simply adapt / use the `'a list`

```
type 'a Stack = 
    | Nil
    | Cons of 'a * 'a Stack
```

Comment: Yes, you are right. You can just do `type 'a Stack = 'a list`. But people may try to implement it themselves for learning purpose.

Comment: I think the main difference is that normally a stack is mutable whilst a discriminated union is immutable - using the DU version `Pop()` would have to return a new stack

Comment: @JohnPalmer I am refering to immutable `stack`, and `list` is immutable as well

Comment: Do you have any link to other articles that implement the stack? They might do this to teach basic functional concepts... (reimplementing basic list is a good exercise).

Comment: @TomasPetricek: I think the OP might refer to [this section](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/F_Sharp_Programming/Advanced_Data_Structures#Stacks) in F# wikibook. The exploratory purpose is mentioned clearly there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*To close the question, I posted my comments as an answer.*

You are correct. To use a list as an immutable stack, you can declare a type abbreviation

```
type 'a Stack = 'a list
```

As @Tomas said, implementing the stack by yourself is a good exercise to learn functional programming. I quote a few first sentences from [*Stack* section](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/F_Sharp_Programming/Advanced_Data_Structures#Stacks) in F# wikibook.

> F#'s built-in list data structure is essentially an immutable stack.
>   While its certainly usable, for the purposes of writing exploratory
>   code, we're going to implement a stack from scratch. We can represent
>   each node in a stack using a simple union.